# Ice Maker dead leg

Tags: plumbing, ice-maker

I'm planning to connect my ice maker to my reverse osmosis filter, which will likely involve drilling a PEX line into the basement & running over to the fridge, back up through the floor.

As a result the existing copper line to the fridge will become a dead leg, six feet long or more.

I believe I need to fix this, but I keep wondering if there's a good reversible fix. I would hate to just chop it all out permanently. Could I splice in a ball valve? Or would the small dead leg to the ball valve still be too big?

If there is no reversible fix, is a cut-and-cap advisable? A plug? Or should I go all the way and try to desolder the branch out of the T-junction?

Lastly, since this is cold water, just confirming legionella is still a concern? Our groundwater gets darn cold in the winter (Zone 5), but in the summer ambient temperature is within legionella growth range.

Comment: What size copper pipe goes to the fridge? If it's rigid copper, could you just connect to that from the PEX instead of drilling new holes in the floor?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to shorten it as much as possible, no sense in having unused pressurized lines.  Do a professional job of soldering it closed or put a quality valve and cap on the line, reducing the possibility of leaks.

Comment: Will the water from the RO system give you the taste you want in the ice cubes?

Comment: I guess I hadn't been worried about taste, maybe something to read about.

It's connected at a tee right now, maybe I can successfully remove the tee and replace it with the appropriate junction. That would be the cleanest with no dead leg.